# How can I sort nodes by in degree with gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases

I need to sort nodes by their out-degree.
In neo4j with cypher query language, I do do something like:

```
MATCH (P1:P)
RETURN P1,size((P1)-->()) as degree 
ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 10
```

In gremlin, I know how to count the out degree for each node:

```
g.V().hasLabel('V')
    .order().by(out('E').count(), desc)
    .limit(10)
```

However, I don't see how to return the count as well as the node itself.

Is there any way to make query like this in gremlin?

Answer (score 1):

You can `project` the degree:

```
g.V().hasLabel('V').
  project('vertex', 'degree')
    .by(identity())
    .by(out('E').count())
    .order().by(select('degree'), desc)
    .limit(10)
```

example: https://gremlify.com/c3bw9gpr36o5k